# Private Server is accessed only by computers with IPs in range 10.10.20.XX

Tags: windows, apache, sockets, networking, proxy

They say that IP addresses between the range 10.0.0.0 up to 10.255.255.255 can be used in private networks.

My work’s network has about 200 computers connected to each other using plain switch. At my office I own 2 computers which are connected to the network. The following configuration is true.

My PC1  
IP: 10.10.20.113 
Windows XP  
Firewalls Off  
No Proxy  
Accessing PC2 from Firefox Browser using http://10.10.20.20  (It Works)

My PC2  (server PC) 
IP:10.10.20.20 
Windows XP, Apache Server 
Firewalls Off 
No Proxy 
 
Server on this PC spits its homepage through the network at http://10.10.20.20

My private/local server above (PC2 with IP: 10.10.20.20) can be accessed only by Computers with IPs  between the range 10.10.20.0 up to 10.10.20.255. A computer on the network that has an IP e.g. 10.10.30.30 throws a time out error. If I change Server's IP to 10.10.30.30 it works on networked computers in the IP range 10.10.30.XX but not on networked computers in the IP range 10.10.20.XX

How can I make my private server be accessed on any computer at the same private network with any IP addresses between the whole private range from 10.0.0.0 up to  10.255.255.255 ? Why god makes life difficult?

Thank U in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your network has a mask length of `/24`. That means that the mask is `255.255.255.0`.  To access a network outside your network, you need a router.  You wrote that you only have a switch so you need to add a router to route between networks.

Devices in the network `10.10.20.0/24` can only connect to devices in the `10.10.20.1` to `10.10.20.254` range.  The `10.10.30.0/24` network has a range of hosts from `10.10.30.1` to `10.10.30.254`.  They are two different networks, and you need a router to route between those networks.

Comment: Thank you friend ! You came to the rescue just on time! Really valuable information for me and looks so right ... In a competitive world when I need to complete a database driven intranet to get me going in the job, people like you enlighten me and give me life. Thanks again. I hope you are well all the time !